# How to update facts in Jess Rules Engine?

Tags: java, rules, jess

In Jess, suppose my Factbase consists of several name-value pairs like

```
(node1 6.5) (node2 100) (node3 0.5)
```

How can I achieve to "update" the values for example the "node1" value from 6.5 to 100 without manually retracting it?

Also, is there a way to "reassert" all the facts, after a certain rule is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Jess's `(modify)` function to modify facts. [As explained in the manual](https://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/memory.html), ordered facts like `(node1 6.5)` are internally represented as unordered facts with a single slot named `__data`, so you can exploit that knowledge to modify them:

```
Jess> (assert (node1 6.5))
<Fact-0>
Jess> (modify 0 (__data 7.5))
<Fact-0>
Jess> (facts)
f-0   (MAIN::node1 7.5)
For a total of 1 facts in module MAIN.
```

Now, given all that, for efficiency I'd still recommend that you use an unordered template like

```
(node (slot index) (slot value))
```

so that your facts look like

```
(node (index 1) (value 6.5))
(node (index 2) (value 100))
```

As regards your last question: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you might look up the `(deffacts)` construct and the `(reset)` function and see if together those will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks! My last question referred to the fact that JESS seems to "deactivate" facts once they were used to fire a rule. For my purposes it would be useful if facts are "always active". For example I fire a rule on fact A and B and after that I have another fact C inserted. A rule which would fire on A and C will not fire now because A is somehow "used already". I dont understand why that is the case.

Comment: The facts aren’t “deactivated”, but a given set of facts will only be used to fire a given rule once. Modifying any one of the facts will make the rule eligible to fire again, though.

Comment: For my purpose, I need the facts to represent some kind of "state" of the system and for that I might need the same fact for different rules. Is this approachable in Jess?